# How to change a vector of Months in R to a numeric value in R

Tags: r, vector

So I have a vector in a data frame in R called Month.  My data frame is called wr200meter.  Here is the output of `wr200meter$Month`:

```
[1] May    June   June   Nov    Oct    March  April 

[8] May    July   July   Sept   June   March  April 

[15] June   Oct    August June   Oct    Sept   June  

[22] August August August
```

When I do `as.numeric(wr200meter$Month)` I get:

```
[1] 6 4 4 7 8 5 1 6 3 3 9 4 5 1 4 8 2 4 8 9 4 2 2 2
```

What I want to get is a decimal number.  For example, for June I want 0.5 and for Sept, I want 0.75.  Could someone please tell me:
1) how to get my desired decimal numbers
2) Where do those outputted numbers from `as.numeric(wr200meter$Month)` come from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the output, I suspect that the `class` of `wr2000meter$Month` is `factor` with some `levels`. When coercing these to numeric, R does not look at the string representation of the `level` at all, but instead the index of the `level`. See Section 8.2.1 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for more details.

In this case, R has conveniently provided the names of the month as well as the abbreviations to us as [built-in constants](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/base/html/Constants.html). However, since your data contains some abbreviations and some full names, we will need to get a little creative here and use `grep` to match partial names as well:

```
d <- factor(c("May", "June", "June", "Nov", "Oct", "March", "April", "May", "July", "July", "Sept", "June", "March", "April", "June", "Oct", "August", "June", "Oct", "Sept", "June", "August", "August", "August"))
sapply(d, function (x) { grep(x, month.name); }) / 12 
 [1] 0.4166667 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.9166667 0.8333333 0.2500000 0.3333333
 [8] 0.4166667 0.5833333 0.5833333 0.7500000 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.3333333
[15] 0.5000000 0.8333333 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.8333333 0.7500000 0.5000000
[22] 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
```

Hence, this should produce the output you are looking for:

```
sapply(wr200meter$Month, function (x) { grep(x, month.name); }) / 12
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 monfac <- factor(substr(mons,1,3), levels=month.abb)
 as.numeric(monfac)/12
 [1] 0.4166667 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.9166667 0.8333333 0.2500000 0.3333333
 [8] 0.4166667 0.5833333 0.5833333 0.7500000 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.3333333
[15] 0.5000000 0.8333333 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.8333333 0.7500000 0.5000000
[22] 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
```

Both `month.abb` and `month.name` are built-in vectors in R. Your vector has a mixture of abbreviations and complete spellings, requiring either trimming as I did or `grep`-ing as @musically_ut did. He used `grep` to find the position in one of those vectors and I created a vector with its levels in the natural order of calendar months, which I then converted to numeric.

There also the very useful ‘zoo’-package, which has the ‘yearmon’ class. It is the year with a fractional month stores as numeric so you can do arithmetic or sorting. This problem could make use of it by subtracting the current year.